# open source hot reload/live update HTTP server

Tags: open-source, software-development, web-development, web-server

I'm looking for a live reloading open source HTTP server. I have a bunch of HTML files (generated by pandoc) which I want to show in my browser and refresh/update the side whenever the HTML changes.

- serves HTML
- auto updates/live updates/hot reloads changes HTML files
- standalone tool (not a plugin for an IDE)
- minimal configuration
- simple binary download
- preferably not NPM based
- preferably some way to trigger a page reload other then changing a file, e.g. by sending a signal to the process

The closes I've found is [live-server](https://github.com/tapio/live-server), but I would prefer a single binary to download and as far as I see cannot be triggered to update externally. I'm pretty sure I had exactly such a tool in the past, there were some capability of triggering a reload externally e.g. when a lazily loaded ressource changed or when not serving HTML files directly but via another web server.

Answer (score 1):

The static site generator, [Eleventy](https://www.11ty.dev/), uses [Browsersync](https://browsersync.io/) to live-reload pages, however this is an NPM module, which means it falls outside your preferences.

Another static site generator, [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com), has an option to enable [Guard-LiveReload](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload) from the [LiveReload Project](http://livereload.com/). There are also browser extensions you can install to force page reloads.